# Randomising while statement order

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

i have been messing around with a search engine and i am trying to get the while statement to run and echo the results in a random order. Here is the code i have now.

```
if ($numrows > 0) {

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

    $id = $row['id'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $description = $row['description'];
    $keywords = $row['keywords'];
    $link = $row['link'];

    echo "<div id='resultbox'><h3><a href='$link'>$title</a></h3><br><p>$description</p></div>";



}
```

I need the while statement in theory to run and display results completely randomly.

Is there anyway this can be done?

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you just sort your mysql results by random with the Order By Random property?

Comment: It grabs the results by keyword in the order the database is in, i can't re-shuffle the database every time the script is ran.

Comment: afuzzyllama, nice one removing your comment.

Comment: Maybe you should look up what `ORDER BY RAND()` actually does before you dismiss it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do `order by rand()` in your query to order the results randomly.

Comment: This is my query $query = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE "; How would i structure this?

Comment: `$query = "select * from search where something = something order by rand()";`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it in that same while statement. I think you have to put the results of the query to a list and then by using its size you can use a random number generator and retrieve elements from it using their indices.

You could also shuffle the list and then retrieve from it in order.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a Foreach instead of a while
2. Count your results before hand.
3. generate an array with ints up to the count of your results.
4. randomize that array with native php function for that.
5. when doing your foreach($k => $v kind) use the next number in the array you scrambled and then unset it.

Comment: but i agree with Eric.  but if you had to do it without mysql access heres an approach.

Answer (score 0):

Besides Using `SELECT * FROM search WHERE row1='1' ORDER BY rand()`

You could:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
shuffle($data);

foreach($row as $k=>$v) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $description = $row['description'];
    $keywords = $row['keywords'];
    $link = $row['link'];

    echo "<div id='resultbox'><h3><a href='$link'>$title</a></h3><br><p>$description</p</div>";
}
```